# Elasticsearch on Hadoop - Should ES nodes be Colocated with Hadoop DataNodes?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

From the Elasticsearch for Hadoop [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/arch.html):

> Whenever possible, elasticsearch-hadoop shares the Elasticsearch
>   cluster information with Hadoop to facilitate data co-location. In
>   practice, this means whenever data is read from Elasticsearch, the
>   source nodes IPs are passed on to Hadoop to optimize task execution.
>   If co-location is desired/possible, hosting the Elasticsearch and
>   Hadoop clusters within the same rack will provide significant network
>   savings.

Does this mean to say that ideally an Elasticsearch node should be colocated with every DataNode on the Hadoop cluster, or am I misreading this?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this joint presentation by Elasticsearch and Hortonworks useful in answering this question:

http://www.slideshare.net/hortonworks/hortonworks-elastic-searchfinal

You'll note that on slides 33 and 34 they show multiple architectures - one where the ES nodes are co-located on the Hadoop nodes and another where you have separate clusters. The first option clearly gives you the best co-location of data which is very important for managing Hadoop performance. The second approach allows you to tune each separately and scale them independently.

I don't know that you can say one approach is better than the other as there are clearly tradeoffs. Running on the same node clearly minimizes data access latency at the expense of a loss of isolation and ability to tune each cluster separately.